# I need to find the first event in an array?

Tags: java, arraylist

Fetch the first Event in the calendar whose eventName is equal to the given name

Parameters:

name - - the Event name of the Event within the ArrayList to be returned

Returns:

the Event in the calendar whose name is equal to the given name, or null if no such Event exists

Code:

```
**This is just for reference, the get is what im stuck on**
ArrayList<Event> calendar;

public TRAPSCalender() {
    calendar = new ArrayList<>();
}

public Event get(String name) {
    if(name != null) {
        return calendar;
    }
}
```

I just can't seem to figure out what the logic behind this is? I have created the calendar array, then my job is to get the name from the event and then in the calendar store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
/*
Fetch the first Event in the calendar whose eventName is equal to the given name

Parameters:
name - - the Event name of the Event within the ArrayList to be returned
Returns:
the Event in the calendar whose name is equal to the given name, or null if no such Event exists
*/

public Event get(String name) {
    for(Event firstEvt: this.calendar) {
        if(firstEvt.getEventName().equals(name)) {  // Used accessor getEventName to access the private var
            return firstEvt;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like is that the ArrayList holds a list of `Event` objects, which have an attribute `eventName`. In your `get(String name)` function you have to search through that ArrayList for an `eventName` that matches the name parameter, then return that `Event`.

That searching might look something like:

```
public Event get(String name) {
   for(Event calEvent: this.calendar) {
      if(calEvent.eventName.equals(name))
         return calEvent;
   }
}
```

Comment: For some reason its not finding the eventName when im using the if statement, its got a red line under "calEvent.eventName" which i named firstE. I believe its because i dont have the var eventName anywhere in my Event class and my name var is private @Elliot

Comment: Since it is private, that makes sense. Do you have a function within the Event class that will return the private variable? If you don't have something like `public String getEvent() { return privateVarHere; }` you might want to write that. I don't know what the Event class looks like.